# Replacing the data in a specific row in the txt file

Tags: c++, file

I'm building a TCP Server application. Two different types of requests come from the client. In the first request type, the client requests a certain number of line information starting from a certain line. For example, the client throws a request like I want to read 3 lines starting at line 5.It's okay so far, I've completed this part, but now let's come to the part where I have difficulty.In the second type of request, the client wants to change the characters in a certain number of lines starting from a certain line.For example change 4 rows starting at row 6.txt file consists of 1s and 0s.txt file is as follows.

```
1
0
1
0
1
```

The txt file should be as follows when two line change requests are received, starting from the fourth line.

```
1
0
1
1
0
```

I don't use index numbers to identify line numbers, instead I first read the entire file with a loop and push the read data into a vector at each iteration. Thus, when I want to read a particular line, I call the desired index of that vector.
The parts of the code that interest us are shown below.

```
std::fstream myfile("fc3-4.txt", std::ios_base::in);
        int reg;
        std::vector<int> registers_vec;
        while (myfile >> reg)
        {
            registers_vec.push_back(reg);
        }
```

As a result of my research, I found to delete a specific data, but this does not work for me because for example, if I write 1 to the value to be deleted, it deletes all the 1s in the txt file.How can I replace a certain number of rows starting from a certain row as I mentioned above.Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't exactly show what doesn't work, but you can delete a single data of a vector by calling [`registers_vec.erase(register_vec.begin() + index)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase).

Comment: @Lala5th Yes, as you said, I can delete the element I want from the vector, but what I really want is to delete the element I want from the txt file and replace it with a new one.

Comment: @Lala5th I use the vector for reading only. But now I need to change the data in the txt file. The changes I made on the vector I use for reading are no longer important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First read the complete file into memory. Then close the file.

Make the modifications in memory.

Then, after modifications have been done, write the complete vector to the file.

E.g.:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

int main() {
    // Open the file and check, if it could be opened
    if (std::ifstream dataStream{ "fc3-4.txt" }; dataStream) {

        // Read all vallues in vector data
        std::vector data(std::istream_iterator<int>(dataStream), {});
        // And close the file
        dataStream.close();


        // Do any modification. Example flip bits for line 6 to 8
        for (size_t line{ 6 }; data.size() > 8 and line < 8; ++line)
            data[line] = 1 - data[line];


        // Write all file to file
        {
            if (std::ofstream dataStream{ "fc3-4.txt" }; dataStream) {

                // Write all data to file
                std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(dataStream, "\n"));
            }
            else std::cerr << "\nError, Cannot open file for writing\n";
        }
    }
    else std::cerr << "\nError, Cannot open file for reading\n";
}
```